# Dynamic page re-render with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to re-render periodically page http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-rub .

This page has dynamic graph, but it's looks like PhantomJS rendered it only once.

```
var page = new WebPage();

var testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false, workInProgress = false;

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function () {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function () {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log("load finished");
};

var steps = [
    function () {
        workInProgress = true;
        page.open("http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-rub", function (status) {
            if (status === "success") {
                page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
                    page.evaluate(function () {
//                console.log("$(\".chartWrap\").html() -> " + $(".chartWrap").html());
                    });

                    var bb = page.evaluate(function () {
//                return document.getElementsByClassName("chartWrap")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                        $(".generalOverlay").remove();
                        $(".mainPopUpContainer").remove();

                        console.log($("#chart-info-last").html());
                        var div = $(".chartWrap")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                        return div;
                    });

//                    page.clipRect = {
//                        top: bb.top,
//                        left: bb.left,
//                        width: bb.width,
//                        height: bb.height
//                    };

                    console.log("Start render usd-rub.png");
                    page.render('usd-rub.png');
                    console.log("End of render usd-rub.png");

                    workInProgress = false;



                });

            }
        });
    },
    function () {
    },
];


steps[0]();

interval = setInterval(function () {


    if (!loadInProgress && !workInProgress) {
        console.log("Start render usd-rub.png");

        page.evaluate(function () {
            $('body').hide();
            $('body').show();
            console.log($("#chart-info-last").html());
        });

        page.render('usd-rub.png');


        console.log("End of render usd-rub.png");
    }

}, 7000);
```

This script shows only one value, not dynamic.

```
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6848
End of render usd-rub.png
```

Is it possible to re-render page without it's reloading (reloading take a lot of time, as I see, but I need fast response)?

Thank you!

Comment: It's changing, about in 5-7 seconds per once. Tested in Google Chrome, 53.0.2756.0 dev-m (64-bit)

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Since jQuery is already included in the page, you should not include your own (ancient) version of jQuery, because it might break all the things

Comment: Very strange! I've added 

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

and now it's works 

Start render usd-rub.png
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6740
End of render usd-rub.png
Start render usd-rub.png
65.6735
End of render usd-rub.png

Comment: I think, that in past attempts some resources were NOT loaded...